# Dataflow override processing time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to override the **processing** time (not the event time) in dataflow?

I'm trying to reason about failure scenarios, and how to re-compute the output of a pipeline.

Say I have a pipeline that simply counts the events received, with a fixed window of 1h and allowed lateness 2h. Say I'm interested in the window [t0, t0+1h), and say I have:

- event A, event time = t0+10m, processing time = t0 + 30m
- event B, event time = t0+10m, processing time = t0 + 90m

Then event A is counted, and event B is discarded.

Now, say that after a few days I discover a bug in the code and I want to re-run the pipeline to re-count events in same past window [t0, t0+1h).
If processing time is now = t0 + few days, then all events will be discarded.

And if I ignore the allowed lateness (assuming infinite), then both event A and B are counted.

By overriding the processing time (assuming I stored it the very first time) I could make sure that event A is counted and event B is not. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing time is the time an element arrives in the system for processing. The watermark tracks where we are in the input stream relative to the event time of elements.

The watermark is often just a heuristic, so when it's wrong and elements come in that are older than expected, those elements will be marked late. It's possible for the watermark to be behind processing time, so elements could arrive after a delay but still not be marked late. For example, if users are playing a mobile game, the watermark will likely adjust for a large network slowdown that results in multiple delayed events. In this case no elements may actually be considered late. But the watermark won't adjust for an occasional user that's playing the game in offline mode, so this might result in late data. See these articles for useful background on watermarks and the Dataflow model: [Streaming 101](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101) and [Streaming 102](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102).

If an unbounded source supports replaying past events, the system will likely be able to get much better watermarks the second time around, so it's unlikely that things that were marked late the first time will still be marked late.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to guarantee, but you could have your pipeline read the input and then write a copy of the data that includes the event time, processing time, and whether or not the element was considered late. For example, the [TriggerExample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/cookbook/TriggerExample.java) writes out a lot of this information to BigQuery to demonstrate how it works. Then if you need to reprocess it exactly, you could run a batch pipeline that reads from the copy and does a backfill. (This is the benefit of a unified batch + streaming programming model!)

Comment: Thank you much Frances, I read the blog posts and that's where the confusion came from originally. The TriggerExample really clarifies a lot.